# Pop up message when clicked on icon on column headers

Tags: r, shiny

While rendering DT table in shiny, is there a way to add pop up icon as shown below. So when user clicks on it, it should show some message :)

```
datatable(iris)  #### while rendering DT table
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention in your comment that you’d like the contents of the
message to also be clickable, you might be interested in [Bootstrap
Popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/). The
`shinyBS` package provides some wrappers for them. However, I couldn’t get
it to work with a datatable header, so I made some custom helpers:

```r
# Enable popovers -- needs to be included again with dynamic content
usePopover <- function() {
  tags$script(HTML(
    "$(function () {
      $('[data-toggle=\"popover\"]').popover()
    })"
  ))
}

popover <- function(tag, content = NULL, title = NULL, options = list()) {
  if (!is.null(names(options))) {
    names(options) <- paste0("data-", names(options))
  }
  
  tag |>
    tagAppendAttributes(
      `data-toggle` = "popover",
      `data-content` = content,
      title = title,
      !!!options
    )
}
```

You can use these in a datatable column header by defining a custom
`columDefs` element for the target column. While we’re there, we can also use
the same mechanism to inject the info icon, after making sure to include the
required dependency in the UI.

Avoiding the sorting behaviour when clicking on the icon in the header takes some extra work. Essentially, you have to make sure the click event doesn't bubble up to the event listeners in the datatable. For the icon, that can be done with JavaScript in a direct click handler on the element. For the popover itself, we can use a different container (`body`, in this case) so that it's no longer included inside the table in the DOM.

Here’s how this comes together:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Need to add FontAwesome manually because no `icon()` calls in UI.
  fontawesome::fa_html_dependency(),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data = iris,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            targets = 4,
            title = paste(
              "Petal.Width",
              icon("info-circle") |>
                popover(
                  tags$a(href = "https://stackoverflow.com", "Stack Overflow"),
                  # Prevent sorting when clicking on popover
                  options = list(html = TRUE, container = "body")
                ) |>
                tagAppendAttributes(
                  # Prevent sorting when clicking on icon
                  onclick = "event.stopPropagation();"
                ) |>
                tagList(usePopover())
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And it ends up looking something like this:

[image: popover on icon in datatable header]

Comment: Great it is working. But I see when we click on icon, the column sorts. I know since we are clicking on it. But can we not avoid it? :) Sorry I did not realize this. Sorting is required but not when clicked on icon

Comment: @manup yeah I noticed that earlier, too. It was a bit trickier to get around that, but I've updated the answer accordingly. Essentially, you have to make sure that the click event doesn't bubble up to the sorting event listeners in the datatable.

Comment: This is really fantastic. I also want to get into your level. But I am not aware of JS. Can you please guide me any good material so that I can get started :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it's solved your problem! Unfortunately I can't think of a specific resource for getting started off the top of my head, but I'll try to remember to let you know if I come across something. I would say though, that some keywords when working with Shiny are definitely Bootstrap and jQuery -- if you need some JS in Shiny, there's a good chance one of those has you covered.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column names like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable(escape = FALSE, {
    colnames(iris) <- c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width", "Petal Length",
       "Petal Width <div title ='Hover tooltip'>info</div>", "Species")
    iris
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

However, things like `shiny::icon("info-circle")` don't in the colnames.

Comment: Thanks. But one changes, Can we make sure the contents "Hover tooltip" is seen when the user stays on it? Because, there will be url placed there. So i need to allow the user to click on the URL . Is this possible?